# Modify spring cloud config server in the client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring boot powered spring cloud application with a configuration server running seperately on port say 8001 on localhost.

Meanwhile, location has been specified in the config client applications/micro services as below in the bootstrap.yml file of the client project.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8001
```

This works absolutely fine.

However when i want to deploy the whole application on different setups, i would need to run the config server on different IPs and Ports.

In that case i can not go and change the IP:Port information of the config server in all the projects, rebuild the jar and deploy them. In fact in most scenarios, Jenkins build the Jars by itself on different environment.

How can we handle such situation? Can we specify an environment variable in the bootstrap.yml, if yes how to do it?

Any suggestion?

Br,

AJ

Comment: Does it solve the purpose - 

java -jar portal/portal.jar --spring.cloud.bootstrap.location=/etc/conf/portal/bootstrap.properties 

Is this issue still there? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use environment variables in your bootstrap.yml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://${configServerHost}:${configServerPort}
```

When you launch your application you only have to add `-DconfigServerHost=localhost -DconfigServerPort=8001`

Comment: Indeed, cli add `--spring.cloud.config.uri=...` or environment variable `SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=...` work without a custom one.

Comment: Ok, just let me give it a shot and will revert in either case. And thanks for the response.

Comment: Bang on target, just a small correction http://${configServerHost}:${configServerPort}

Comment: @codependent when you enter these command in the cli,  -DconfigServerHost=localhost -DconfigServerPort=8001 would they become env variables?

Comment: @Jesse not really. They are registered as System properties. On the other hand you don't need to use -D arguments if configServerHost and ConfigServerPort are env variables. Choose whichever you prefer.